# Integer with range from 0 to 255

Tags: c, struct, integer, ip

I want to declare a structure with 4 integer and each of them can only be from 0 to 255. Is there a way for it? Currently, I'm doing it by checking the input(in the input function).

```
struct
{ 
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    int num4;
} ip;
```

Comment: Please tag this with the language you are using and share the relevant code.

Comment: @StephenC: There is no "byte" type in C

Comment: Put a shirt on dude! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use bitfield types for this:

```
struct ip 
{
    unsigned num1 : 8;
    unsigned num2 : 8;
    unsigned num3 : 8;
    unsigned num4 : 8;
};
```

Comment: Thank you.How can I do the same thing for Java?

Comment: I'm not sure of the idiomatic way to do this in Java - perhaps a setter function that clamps the provided number to the required range?

Comment: @NguyễnDuy: If you're so concerned with java then why are you askjing the question in terms of C?

Comment: @EdS. Because I need to do the same thing for both C and Java.

Comment: -1, **WHY** would use use an abomination like bitfields when there's a perfectly clean correct way to do it?

Comment: @R: This is just about the only actual portable use for bitfields, and it demonstrates the technique that can be used for other power-of-two ranges like 0..511.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can use `unsigned char` (or, better, `uint8_t`), but that doesn't mean you can just stop checking the input. It depends on your requirements.  If I enter `256` what should happen?  Is overflow ok?

On a side note, `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1, but one byte is not defined to be 8 bits.  On most hardware you'll be fine, but you'd be better served using `uint8_t` for that reason.

Comment: Can I store an integer value to it directly then? For example:
      blablabla->num1 = 1;
Will the work?

Comment: @NguyễnDuy yes. But as EdS. says, you need to think about how blablabla->num = 256; should be handled, especially if 256 comes from input.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. Side question though. How can I do the same thing in Java? Because I don't think Java let you declare an unsigned char ,does it?

Comment: @NguyễnDuy: Java doesn't have unsigned bytes, so you'll use an int and you'll have to `& 0xFF`.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Thank you

Comment: @NguyễnDuy: `int myUnsignedByte = input & 0xFF`.  Note that this line will simply clip, i.e., if I enter `12345` the result will be `255`.